# Log4j2 ExtendedLoggerGenerator CLI is missing class Strings

Tags: java, log4j2

I am trying to generate my own logger. In the documentation [here](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/customloglevels.html#CustomLoggers) of Log4j2 you can generate a Java class with this CLI.

```
java -cp log4j-core-2.19.0.jar org.apache.logging.log4j.core.tools.ExtendedLoggerGenerator \
    com.mycomp.ExtLogger DIAG=350 NOTICE=450 VERBOSE=550 > com/mycomp/ExtLogger.java
```

Unfortunately I always get this error message. I have already tried to include log4j-api-2.19.0.jar in the classpath.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/logging/log4j/util/Strings
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.util.Integers.parseInt(Integers.java:43)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.util.Integers.parseInt(Integers.java:54)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.tools.Generate$LevelInfo.<init>(Generate.java:1044)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.tools.Generate$LevelInfo.parse(Generate.java:1051)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.tools.Generate.generate(Generate.java:1097)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.tools.Generate.generate(Generate.java:1063)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.tools.Generate.access$100(Generate.java:48)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.tools.Generate$ExtendedLogger.main(Generate.java:1030)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.tools.ExtendedLoggerGenerator.main(ExtendedLoggerGenerator.java:28)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.logging.log4j.util.Strings
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at 
java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
```

***Edit:***
Ok, you have to give these 2 JAR's at the same time then it works

```
java -cp log4j-api-2.19.0.jar;log4j-core-2.19.0.jar org.apache.logging.log4j.core.tools.ExtendedLoggerGenerator ExtLogger DIAG=350 NOTICE=450 VERBOSE=550 > ExtLogger.java
```

Comment: log4j-core doesn't include that class. It is in log4j-api. Your question does *not* show log4j-api in the classpath.

Comment: Yes that is the problem, in log4j-api-2.19.0.jar the class ExtendedLoggerGenerator does not exist for this purpose

Comment: Put both jars on your classpath.

Comment: I have already tried that too.I work on Windows. I have added both JAR's to the classpath. With %PATH% the 2 JAR's were displayed to me in the CMD

Comment: `PATH` and `CLASSPATH` are different things: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I updated my question. The classpath is now also displayed

Comment: `-cp` overrides the `CLASSPATH` environment variable.

Comment: omg, no it is working! I add both JAR on the same time. thank you->java -cp log4j-api-2.19.0.jar;log4j-core-2.19.0.jar org.apache.logging.log4j.core.tools.ExtendedLoggerGenerator ExtLogger DIAG=350 NOTICE=450 VERBOSE=550 > ExtLogger.java

Comment: Thanks, it's working with the 2 jars (I'm on Linux, so the separator is `:` instead of `;`).